# Javascript, rounding and calculating values against original values

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding, rounding-error

I'm trying to calculate a series of values which should aggregate to the same as the Original Value.

[image: Example]

If you look at the above example, you can see that the aggregated cost and billed figures are aggregating to 239.99 and 219.98 respectively. They obviously need to aggregate to 240 and 220 respectively.

The cost and billed figures are calculated when Hours changes (by using a jQuery on change function). The multiplier is determined by dividing the `Original Value Hours` by the number specified in the `Calculated Values Hours` below.

(0.2 / 0.7) = 0.28571428571428575

(0.3 / 0.7) = 0.4285714285714286

Self-evidently, the figures need to aggregate to the Original Values.

This is an issue no doubt to do with floating point precision and rounding and I've tried using the following function without success:-

```
    function to2DP(num, fixed) {
        var re = new RegExp('^-?\\d+(?:\.\\d{0,' + (fixed || -1) + '})?');
        return num.toString().match(re)[0];
    }   

    $("#splitTimeContainer").on("change", ".changeHours", function(e) {
        var splitID = $("#splitID").val();
        var splitOrigCost = $("#splitOrigCost").val();
        var splitOrigBilled = $("#splitOrigBilled").val();
        var splitOrigHours = $("#splitOrigHours").val();
        var i = 1;

        var divideMe = $(this).val();

        var coEfficient = (divideMe/splitOrigHours);

        var newCost = to2DP((coEfficient * splitOrigCost), 2);

        var newBilled = to2DP((coEfficient * splitOrigBilled), 2);

        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

        parent.find('.changeCost').val(newCost);

        parent.find('.changeBilled').val(newBilled);

    });
```

As well as using toFixed, but again without success.

Anyone have any suggestions at how I go about achieving this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - also try using toFixed as close to the end as possible

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about rounding and mathematics.

- I recommend to use different rounding [to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). This rounding at least has no bias so it will not systematically increase or decrease values.
- Another problem is that even with this rounding there is no guarantee that sum of values will match due to odd number of calculated values.

In this particular example this rounding will achieve cost 240 and billed 220.01.
This problem in my opinion has not optimal solution.
Consider this:

```
Hours: 0.9, Cost 100
hours: 0.3, cost 33.33
hours: 0.3, cost 33.33
hours: 0.3, cost 33.33
```

There is no way how to make this working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding the amount lost during division to one or more values.

Splitwise also does that to ensure no loss of value.